# Use slicer to filter values containing text

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet listing reporting requirements. One column includes the months in which the requirements apply. E.g. "1, 4, 7, 10" for a requirement in January, April, July and October. Or "7" if the requirement only apples in July.

I want an user friendly way to filter the requirements in a specific month.

- A pivot table with a filter works. The downside is that users
  manually have to enter the number (or select both options) to get all
  requirements in July.
- The same applies for using a slicer.

I want to do this macro-free to make it as user friendly as possible (e.g. a slicer with values 1 to 12, whereby selecting 7 also includes the earlier option with multiple values). I can change the data model (e.g. add additional columns) if that helps. In order to easily maintain the data, I have a strong preference to not add additional lines (such as a line per month)

Comment: slicers are naturally exclusive, so if you want to use a slicer to do sets that overlap each other, you would have to add rows, but you're right to not want that - when the filter is off, you'll get double data